# VSS Show differences truncating results

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Visual Sourcesafe, version 8.0.50727.1551 (32-bit)

I have a C# class in VSS that I'd like to view the differences between versions.  I am able to go through and show history for the class, and then I can select the 2 versions I wish to compare and see the differences.  However, if I click on "Report" and then "Preview", it just shows me a list of the dates of changes and not the details (even though "Show Details" is checked).  And if instead of clicking "Report" I instead click "Diff", I see the details but the data is truncated and I only see the first 40-50 characters of code on each line.

Is there a way to get the actual difference through one of these 2 buttons that shows all of the code changes and doesn't cutoff the right hand side of the code on each line?

And yes VSS sucks, we're moving to TFS, but not something I can enact immediately so I'm stuck with VSS for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the detailed differences between 2 versions by click Diff and then click OK. Or you have to get a report for it?